# Thor: Ragnarok worldwide release dates

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, behind-the-scenes, thor-ragnarok

As anyone in North America is noticing right now from all the online reviews, *Thor: Ragnarok* is getting released under a relatively unusual [international release schedule](http://www.viva-press.com/release-dates/thor-ragnarok-release-dates/) that puts most of Western Europe<sup>1</sup> a full 10 days ahead of North America, with Asia, South America and Eastern Europe all mixed up.

## What are the factors that went into this schedule?

> 24 October 2017 - UK, Taiwan
> 25 October 2017 - Belgium, France, Indonesia, Italy, South Korea, Philippines, Poland
> 26 October 2017 - Australia, Brazil, Chile, Netherlands, New Zealand, Singapore
> 27 October 2017 - Bulgaria, Estonia, Spain, Croatia, Iceland, Norway, Romania, Sweden, Turkey, Vietnam, South Africa
> 31 October 2017 - Germany
> 1 November 2017 - Hungary, Serbia
> 2 November 2017 - Armenia, Argentina, Denmark, Greece, Israel, Russia, Ukraine
> 3 November 2017 - Bahamas, Canada, China, Hong Kong, India, Japan, Sri Lanka, Lithuania, USA

---

<sup>1</sup> Yes, I know about Germany.  I'm generalizing.

Comment: I would also add this speculation:  they wouldn't want to move the US earlier so it's still relatively fresh for Thanksgiving week.  Don't know why they wouldn't just put everywhere around Nov 3, though.

Comment: “a relatively unusual international release schedule” — just speaking for the UK, we’ve been getting MCU movies about a week before America for some time.

Comment: Additional speculation:   Don't want to release the weekend of Halloween parties in the US?

Comment: No-one goes to the movies on Purge night eh.

Comment: This question is for movies SE, nevertheless neither +1 nor -1.

Comment: @atayenel:   That is a misconception; that's not how it works.   This site is for all questions related to science fiction and fantasy works.   Even ones that are not about the content of the works themselves.   Someone else can link meta.

Comment: ... perhaps @Valorum

Comment: @ThePopMachine I’m waiting for the meta link. After that I’m happy to remove my comment. I will also learn something new

Comment: @atayenel, https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350/what-questions-are-on-topic-and-what-questions-are-off-topic/356.   If you have questions, take it to the meta.

Comment: @atayenel:   Perhaps [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28710/what-is-the-reason-john-williams-did-not-compose-more-for-the-harry-potter-movie) is a good example.   Strictly speaking the question has nothing to do with the scifi-ness of the Harry Potter movies.   You could ask exactly the same question about any movie series.   But because it is about Harry Potter movies, it is **on topic**.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - You don't need a meta, it's right there on the main [FAQ](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page; **What questions can I ask?** - "*Behind-the-scenes and fandom information*"

Comment: In the UK wednesday has become a traditional movie opening night. Until a couple of years ago one of the mobile networks would allow anyone on its network to have 2 4 1 cinema tickets on Orange Wednesday this meant wed became the most popular movie going day of the week and therefore films would open on a weds in the uk and the following Friday or later in the us.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this ScreenRant article](https://screenrant.com/marvel-movies-release-week-later-early-explained/), it's nothing more than marketing strategy.  Since the release of *Iron Man 2* in 2010, Marvel's films have been released earlier in international markets both to build hype and to inflate opening-weekend box office statistics. (According to the article, part of the reason for the latter is so that they can always post better numbers than DC Comics' movies.)

Comment: That is a wonderful find.   I recommend a longer explanation of the key points of the article.